# In C#, what's the best way to search a list of a class by one of the class's members?

Tags: c#, search, list

Say I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    int m_member;

    public int Member {
        get { return m_member; }
        set { m_member = value; }
    }
}
```

And somewhere else, I have a list of type `List<SomeClass> list`.

If I want to search the list for a particular instance of the class, I can just do

```
int index = list.IndexOf(someInstance);
```

But if I want to search the list by Member, I have to do this:

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
    if (list[i].Member == someMember) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int index = list.FindIndex(m => m.Member == someMember);
```

Comment: If you need the item *instead* of the index, you can use `Find()` instead of `FindIndex()` (Not what the OP asked for, just an FYI).

Comment: Thanks 280Z28, that comes in useful elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use Linq

```
SomeClass aClasss = list.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Member == someMember);
```

Comment: If you're using `List<T>`, this isn't what you want, but it does work for finding an item in an enumeration - note that it doesn't find the index of the item though.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an extended search method(using reflection) for the list like below where property name and search value are input parameters.

```
public static List<T> SearchList<T>(this List<T> list, string PropertyName, string SearchValue)
{
    return list.Select(item =>
        new
        {
            i = item,
            Props = item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        })
        .Where(item => item.Props.Any(p =>
        {
            var val = p.GetValue(item.i, null);
            return val != null
                && (p.Name.ToLower() == PropertyName.ToLower() || string.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertyName))
                && (val.ToString().ToLower().Contains(SearchValue.ToLower()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchValue));
        }))
        .Select(item => item.i)
        .ToList();
    }
```

calling:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
var searchedEmployees = data.SortList(serachProperty, searchValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Buddha. I think you can make this less messy/slow with a few suggestions: 1. Normalize using `ToLowerInvariant` instead of `ToLower`; 2. Normalize `PropertyName` and `SearchValue` once at the beginning of the method, rather than in lambdas that will be invoked in nested loops; 3. Check `string.IsNullOrEmpty` *before* referencing the string, not after; 4. There is no need for either `Select` clause, suggest to remove them and get the properties in the `Where` clause instead.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this answer: Consider whether using reflection is really the right choice for your scenario. Using reflection is slow, adds unnecessary complexity, and loses most of the benefits of type safety. Consider designing a solution tailored to your specific filtering scenario instead.